# Erro na chave do dicionário

Tags: python-3.x, lista, dicionário

Eu estou tentando armazenar dicionários em uma lista e depois imprimir de acordo com a posição na lista, porém esta dando um erro na chave...
Código abaixo:

```
nome = "nomedahora"
cpf = "1421241"
departamento = "bsi"
dicProfessor = {nome: {"nome":nome, "cpf":cpf, "departamento":departamento}}
listaProfessores = []
listaProfessores.append(dicProfessor)
dicProfessor.clear()
for item in listaProfessores:
    print(item[nome])
```

Erro:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Aluno/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/rqwrqrqr.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       print(item[nome]) KeyError: 'nomedahora'

Comment: Faça a chamada do dicProfessor.clear() após terminar de iterar a lista e não antes, fazendo antes vc vai remover a referência dele na lista.

Answer (score 3):

Quando você adiciona um dict numa lista, você esta adicionando apenas uma referencia, não uma copia. Por exemplo:

```
>>> professor = {
>>>     'nome': 'Alan Turing'
>>> }
>>> print (professor)
{'nome': 'Alan Turing'}
>>> professores = [professor]
>>> print (professores)
[{'nome': 'Alan Turing'}]
>>> professor.clear()
>>> print (professores)
[{}]
```

no momento em que você executa o professor.clear(), ele limpa tanto da variável professor, quanto da variável professores, pois o conteúdo aponta pro mesmo dict. Uma solução é inserir uma copia do dict no vetor, em vez da referencia. Para isso, use o método `copy()` do dict.

```
>>> professor = {
>>>     'nome': 'Alan Turing'
>>> }
>>> print (professor)
{'nome': 'Alan Turing'}
>>> # aqui fazemos uma copia, em vez de adicionar a referencia.
>>> professores = [professor.copy()]
>>> print (professores)
[{'nome': 'Alan Turing'}]
>>> professor.clear()
>>> print (professores)
[{'nome': 'Alan Turing'}]
```